# how to apply validation before taking the values to the next page in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a requirement where i have multistep registration form. I get the values in a form and i pass it to the next page via `post` method and before that i have to ensure that the values are present for those fields that were marked as required. I use `devise` for the registration and i have used the custom registration with the `devise`.

I have added `validates_presence_of :username` in the user model and when i submit the form it simply takes to the next page even if the field does not contain any value. I use rails4.

So please tell me how to `validate` the fields and stay on the same page before taking it to the next page?

**UPDATE:**

registration_controller

```
    def signup_step3
        @user = User.new
    end

    def signup_step4
        @user = User.new
    end


    # POST /users
    def create
        @user = User.new(params[:user])

        respond_to do |format|
             if @user.save
                 format.html {redirect_to new_user_session_path, notice: 'User was successfully created.'}
             else
                 format.html {render user_registration_path, notice: 'User cannot be created.'}
             end
         end
    end
```

and model file contains

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable
  validates_presence_of :username
end
```

Comment: Please paste your controller code for the create action

Comment: Please update your question with the Controller and Model file. Also, check your console to check whats happening

Comment: As i said i did not take the values to the create action and instead i take the input values to the next page and from there i have to take to the create.

Comment: Hey, validates_presence_of is a Model validation. If you do not try to save it, then how you can validate it?

Comment: ok, i understand that but how can i validate the field before saving? I tried adding the "required: true" in the input field in view which does not allow to take to the next page but it does not show any error. So tell me how i could validate before saving

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate form fields before submitting the form you should consider using client side validation . You can use JavaScript through jQuery to achieve this.

Without actually providing a clear cut answer, I highly recommend you to read more about this topic, since there is plenty of information to be find.

Answer (score 0):

Multistage registration and its validation form has been covered thoroughly on [RailsCasts #217](http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms?view=asciicast). Or you can use [the Wizard gem](http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked) if you don't want to do it from scratch.